# Move matrix visualization total to left side

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have a Matrix visualization with about 20 columns.  PowerBI's Matrix shows the total to the right and bottom.  My users would like to see the total to the very left instead of right.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

No, the Matrix visualization has no built-in control over the location of the Total rows or columns.  You will need to develop your own custom visualization.

Perhaps you would be better served switching to a Table visualization and adding your own Total column on the left side?

Comment: Hi.  Thanks but I meant the "Total" column that PowerBI generates automatically and puts it at the very right hand side and I want it in the very left.  Sorry if my question wasn't clear.  I'm using a "matrix" visualization.  In the layout, I have only one column field and one value field.  The data on the visulalization creates a matrix with about 20 values that goes horizontally and PowerBI creates a total and puts it at the end.

Comment: Thanks Degan.  I'll try that.